# How to make the text touch the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page with somewhat large text elements. I want the text to align to the bottom of the containing div so that it touches the bottom of the div.

I tried following but still there is some space between the text and the bottom. Is there any way I can remove this space and make the text touch the bottom?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/x8j0e192/) is a live sample of what I have tried.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bottomAlignedText {
            position: relative;
        }
        .bottomAlignedText span {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bottomAlignedText" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid;">
    <span style="font-size:300px;">Test</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

```css
.bottomAlignedText {
  position: relative;
}
.bottomAlignedText span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="bottomAlignedText" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid;">
    <span style="font-size:300px;">Test</span>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have one question. Would this `0.7` line height work for all fonts and font sizes?

Comment: However, it just causes unreadability if there are more than one line.

Comment: I think the best option here is to use `line-height`, other options are to use negative `bottom`  https://jsfiddle.net/x8j0e192/9/ or negative `margin-bottom` https://jsfiddle.net/x8j0e192/10/. There are probably other options but...